# How to run openshift MEAN project in localhost or development system Ubuntu?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mean.io

I have created a MEAN stack application on https://openshift.redhat.com/ and it was successfully running on the web.

Default source code of the project synced form: https://github.com/linnovate/mean-on-openshift.git

For further development I am cloning the hosted git source using using git url mentioned in the applications page. (e.g `git clone ssh://55e86e9f89f5cf1d29000001@nodejs-tapslab.rhcloud.com/~/git/nodejs.git/`).

After clone the source code to local system, opening the project in sublime text editor. I can see in the `config/env/development.js` there are lot of configuration are used like `process.env.OPENSHIFT_XXX`. I was changed the some config value mentioned below and trying to start server using command : 'node server', but server was not starting throwing error.

```
{
db:  db: 'mongodb://' + (process.env.DB_PORT_27017_TCP_ADDR || 'localhost:27017') + ':' + '/mean-dev',
hostname: process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || 'http://localhost:3000'
}
```

Can someone help me how to run Openshift mean project in local system and what all configuration needed before running it in local system.

System Config :

```
Ubuntu 12.04
MongoDB v2.6.6
Nodejs v0.10.40
npm 1.4.28
grunt-cli v0.1.13
```

Error :

```
$ node server

    Mean app started on port 3000 (development)

    events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
     Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
    at errnoException (dns.js:37:11)
    at Object.onanswer [as oncomplete] (dns.js:124:16)
```

Comment: Is the code that you post the error that you're getting? Also; what local system are you running on?

Comment: Thanks, for response, System info and error updated in the post. Please help, thanks.

Comment: `db:  db: 'mongodb://'`, isn't that a typo ?

Answer (score 2):

Git:

```
$ NODE_ENV=test node server
```